# Patching Kernel 3.1.5

Tags: 11.10, kernel, updates, intel-wireless, patch

I recently installed kernel 3.1.5 (upgraded from kernel 3.1.4) and now my wireless doesnt work. After some investigating, I found that the iwlagn module no longer exists. Apparently this is a documented problem with this kernel. So, my questions are:

1) Can I apply the Fedora community patch (it has already been solved there) for this kernel to my Ubuntu kernel?

2) If not, where could I apply for a patch to this problem? Would it be easier to compile the kernel myself and make some small change?

3) I asked this on the forum already, but didnt get a response: Why are there so many kernels listed and could it be assumed that each increase in version number results in a more efficient or updated kernel?

4) Will I be able to update this kernel through a ppa or will I need to manually apply patches and updates?

My laptop uses Ubuntu 11.10, an intel i5 processor and hd 3000 graphics w/ intel 6150 centrino N wireless card. The reason I am updating the kernel is because my resume/suspend function doesnt work (backlight never turns back on), power consumption is terrible, and taking advantage of the intel graphics appears to require a more updated kernel. Finally, why does the official update only include kernel 3.0.*? I noticed that kernel 3.1.5 was labeled as the"Precise" OS. Are these kernels optimized for Ubuntu 11 vs Ubuntu 12?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually answered a lot of my own questions here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900297

Let me know if anything seems incorrect.